# Session Store IQueryable in HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0

I am migrating project from Net MVC to MVC Core 2.

How do I set IQueryable in Sessions?
In Net MVC it was the following,

```
    public ActionResult CurrentOwners_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int propertyID)
    {
        if (propertyID == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyID");
        }

        IQueryable<PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel> allResult = (IQueryable<PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel>)HttpContext.Session.GetString(_currentOwnersResult).AsQueryable();

        if (allResult == null)
        {
            PropertyOwnerManager propertyOwnerManager = new PropertyOwnerManager();
            allResult = propertyOwnerManager.GetPropertyOwnershipSummary(propertyID).AsQueryable();
            Session.Add(_currentOwnersResult, allResult);  
        }
```

**Last Line above is giving Error:**

```
The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
```

_currentOwnersResult is string
AllResult is IQueryable

When trying to convert in MVC Core, the following does not work either

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(_currentOwnersResult, allResult);
```

**Error Code:**

```
cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<HPE.Kruta.Model.PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel>' to 'string'
```

Comment: An IQueryable is a query that hasn't run yet, not data that needs storing. Even in MVC. I'd expect a variable called `allResult` to containt he *results* of a query anyway, not the query itself. Perhaps the actual type is IEnumerable<T> ?

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Comment: @JoeSmith it didn't work there either. It's not a matter of syntax. How was that `allResult` created?

Comment: @JoeSmith as for the *context* and *session*, 1) what does `does not work` mean? 2) Where did you find that `HttpContext`? In ASP.NET Core MVC the context is no longer a singleton object, it's injected in the constructor. This allows easy testing of the controllers too. In the latest Razor Pages, it's once again a singleton, but easier to test

Comment: @JoeSmith did you check [Session and app state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) ? Have you [configured the session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-session-state)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so as a basic example on how to setup a complex object in your Session in .NET Core:

First setup your session:

In your Startup.cs, under the Configure method, add the following line:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
app.UseSession();
}
```

And under the ConfigureServices method, add the following line:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //Added for session state
  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

  services.AddSession(options =>
  {
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);               
  });
}
```

To add complex objects in your list to your Session (Please note that this an example only and not specific to your case since I do not know what PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel definiton is):

Model:

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string DesignationId { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDetailsDisplay
{
    public EmployeeDetailsDisplay()
    {
        details = new List<EmployeeDetails>();
    }
    public List<EmployeeDetails> details { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a SessionExtension helper to set and retrieve your complex object as JSON:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
        {
            public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
            {
                session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            }

            public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
            {
                var value = session.GetString(key);

                return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
            }
        }
```

Adding this complex object to your session:

```
 //Create complex object
 var employee = new EmployeeDetailsDisplay();

 employee.details.Add(new EmployeeDetails
 {
 EmployeeId = "1",
 DesignationId = "2"
 });

 employee.details.Add(new EmployeeDetails
 {
 EmployeeId = "3",
 DesignationId = "4"
 });
//Add to your session
HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("EmployeeDetails", employee);
```

And finally to retrieve your complex objects from your Session:

```
var employeeDetails = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<EmployeeDetailsDisplay>("EmployeeDetails");

//Get list of all employee id's
List<int> employeeID = employeeDetails.details.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.EmployeeId)).ToList();
//Get list of all designation id's
List<int> designationID= employeeDetails.details.Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.DesignationId)).ToList();
```

Comment: also, let me know if you have answer for this, thanks, trying to figure this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254563/net-core-return-http-badrequest-in-json-format